Unused Arguments in EBImage normalize() function
I have been trying to run the code in R to normalize an image and clip the channel at 0.2. However, I keep getting an issued argument for anything I put after the first argument. inputRange is listed as an argument in the documentation.
norm_images <- normalize(cur_images, inputRange = c(0, 0.2))

I tried adding other arguments in such as separate or ft and those also did not work despite being listed in the API.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What packages do you currently have loaded? Is is possible you have more than one normalize function defined?

Try using  EBImage::normalize() instead of just function name normalize(). Share your sessionInfo.
